# AWS Cloudfront Presigned URL error "no such key"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, pre-signed-url

I'm creating an Amazon presigned url to give my Cloudfront links an expiry date.

The link works, showing that the object is accessible (parts in **bold** protected for Stack Overflow):

> http://**MY CLOUDFRONT
>   URL**/3304686e4a1176617a0d515ec69abd1e4e765d4c3730e14c7.mp3

However the object with a policy attached does not work.

> http://**MY CLOUDFRONT
>   URL**/3304686e4a1176617a0d515ec69abd1e4e765d4c3730e14c7.mp3?Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiaHR0cDovL2QzMGk2b214eWxiZ3FxLmNsb3VkZnJvbnQubmV0L2F1ZGlvLzEtODNiNjMzMDQ2ODZlNGExMTc2NjE3YTBkNTE1ZWM2OWFiZDFlNGU3NjVkNGMzNzMwZTE0YzcubXAzIiwiQ29uZGl0aW9uIjp7IkRhdGVMZXNzVGhhbiI6eyJBV1M6RXBvY2hUaW1lIjoxNTcyNTIwNDU2fX19XX0_&Signature=Ch4GtdMAKDe8cdBCzAMDEj3C6QeDoc68P76V0iDfH-gNawYlTqQ9M04jZB2PL4weJuV~6nLT8HlHImJvtVdD17J4P1Lva24r3IC5bTdWlMVDOqOlpAV81yMppmg7kNi6Y6ySBofZ~4e-WyDeDTqGLbcG~TQxOWOwppHaVN9nuPaLu8JX2iHD28BqHDghQXR-dGRjbCVfku5SHXsAVXPZMBEaAhpGxBMFE00gho6rGUKtgH8-TOiUmGWsxlBNjx1SGBKAwwiV~m-uKBR~6m5qLrEgJI28XmESZKjidrQsaH~qbYVVyr-cyYTsJOunOSPgpyI52RJg4jkg7kJLqU9kzQ__&Key-Pair-Id=**MY
>   KEY PAIR ID**

results in the following error

[image]

How do I establish what is wrong with my signing policy? Is it possible to debug this signed url? As far as I can establish from the documentation it should work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like even though you have created CloudFront signed URL (not pre-signed URL), you haven't enabled "Restrict Viewer Access" in the Cache behaviour , it you haven't enabled it, it'll not work.
[CloudFront Signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-trusted-signers.html)

Since you have not Restrict Viewer Access enabled and you have "Cache based on query string" select to ALL , CloudFront is sending the object name and the query string to Origin S3 and S3 doesn't have the object with this complete name (object+querystring).

The error is from S3, not from CloudFront, your CloudFront signed url looks correct.

```
{"Statement":[{"Resource":"http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/audio/1-83b63304686e4a1176617a0d515ec69abd1e4e765d4c3730e14c7.mp3","Condition":{"DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":1572520456}}}]}
```